# Java EL evaluate property on bean

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have a variable `${path}` which contains a String "a.b.c" And I would like to evaluate this as a property of an object ${object} :

if I try `${object[path]}` it throw a "Property not found"

I would be written as :

```
${object.a.b.c}
```

I can split on "." and do a for loop object = object[split[i]]

But I find it ugly.

I would like something like :

```
eval("object."${path})
```

is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create and evaluate a *ValueExpression* using a bean or function as an intermediary:

```
package hoteval;

import javax.el.*;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;

@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class Expr {
  public Object eval(PageContext pageContext, String expression) {
    ExpressionFactory factory = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory()
            .getJspApplicationContext(pageContext.getServletContext())
            .getExpressionFactory();
    ELContext elCtxt = pageContext.getELContext();
    ValueExpression ve = factory
                     .createValueExpression(elCtxt, expression, Object.class);
    return ve.getValue(elCtxt);
  }
}
```

The invocation syntax looks like this:

```
${expr.eval(pageContext, "${bean.prop}")}
```

*Written/tested against Glassfish 4.0.*

---

The above code is just an example. To serve an expression of the form `${expr.eval(pageContext, object, path)}` where *path* is `a.b.c` it could be rewritten as:

```
  public Object eval(PageContext pageContext, Object o, String path) {
    expression = "${_tmpRootObject."+expression+"}";
    pageContext.setAttribute("_tmpRootObject", o);
    //etc.
```

The evaluation code could equally become a function taking the form `ex:eval(...`.

Regarding the comment about using an ELResolver.

- You would add an *ElResolver* to the [JspApplicationContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext.html) (see above) in a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).
- It will get called before most other resolvers - [see order](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext.html#addELResolver%28javax.el.ELResolver%29).
- But now you have some problems in [getValue(ELContext, Object, Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html#getValue%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29).

  - For `${object[path]}` you get whatever value *path* resolves to and need to distinguish between it and other properties (bean properties/map values/etc.)
  - Looking for a string instance containing `.` might be enough so long as you check the base type is not a *Map*.
  - You will probably have to split the string and use reflection to look for the properties.
  - I don't think nested evaluation (resolving a *ValueExpression* in an *ELResolver*) is supported but I may be wrong.

Comment: as my knowledge of EL improve, I think that the best way to solve my problem would be to write a custom ELResolver and add it in last position in the array of El Resoler. But for now I don't know how to do this.